# Accessing toolbar from extjs Grid

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I have a requirement where I have a number instances of a custom Grid (called PackageGrid).

This Grid has a default Toolbar with a couple of buttons. However for each instance of the Grid that I create, some additional widgets can be added to the toolbar using the insert method on the toolbar like so :

> tBar.insert(0, {xtype:'button'})

My first approach was to define a custom toolbar and assign it to a variable, and then add that variable to my Grid, like so :

```
var tb = Ext.create('js.grid.Toolbar') //my custom toolbar


Ext.define('js.grid.PackageGrid', {

    referenceToToolbar: tb,

    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',

    tbar: tb //this.toolbar
});
```

I hold a reference to the toolbar called **referenceToToolbar**. I then later grab this toolbar reference and add my widgets.

```
this.packageGrid = Ext.create('js.grid.PackageGrid')

var tBar = this.packageGrid.referenceToToolbar;

tBar.insert(0, {....})
```

The problem with this approach is that when I add widgets using **tBar.insert(..)** to my grid instances, ALL of my grids isntances get the same widgets... because, while the Grids are seperate instances, there is only one toolbar instance shared across all grids (tb).

I have tried playing around with the **initComponent** method to create an instance of the toolbar.

Basically I need ONE instance of a toolbar for ONE instance of my grid. And then be able to get a reference to that toolbar (before render time), and add some more widgets.

Can that be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass additional toolbar item as configuration into grid. Then in grid's `initComponent` method you can create grid's `tbar` with merged items (shared and additional).

So your grid definition could be like this:

```
Ext.define('js.grid.PackageGrid', {

    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',

    initComponent: function() {
        var me = this;

        me.initTbar();

        me.callParent();

    },
    initTbar: function() {

        var me = this;

        var tbarItems = [{
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'Shared Button'
        }];

        if (me.aditionalTbarItems && me.aditionalTbarItems.length) {

            tbarItems = me.aditionalTbarItems.concat(tbarItems);
        }

        me.tbar = tbarItems;
    }    
});
```

Then you can pass additional toolbar items in configuration when you are creating instance of your grid:

```
var grid1 = Ext.create('js.grid.PackageGrid', {
    title: 'Grid 1',
    aditionalTbarItems: [{
       xtype: 'button',
       text: 'Grid 1 Button'
    }],
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

**Fiddle with example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/70q**